# How to remove unwanted line from 2d trimming?

Tags: autocad

I have a problem when I'm extruding a trimmed surface, it's look alright in isometric view, but in 2d view it shows unrelated line due to the trimming of the circle as show in the photo below, any idea to remove it so that the 2d view looks normal which how it should be

Sample image unwanted line

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the object only appears in the 2D view and that you can't select it in any view? You haven't clearly stated why you can't just delete it like any other feature.

Answer (score 1):

Find and delete the object(s) causing the lines.